# How to set button size in WPF if shortcut key is used?

Tags: wpf, button

I use Margin="3" and Padding="5,1,5,1" with my buttons in wpf. I realized if I set a shortcut key like this:

```
<Button Content="_Decide types" Command="{Binding DecideTypesCommand}" 
                ToolTip="Select rows before pressing this button!"/>
```

Then this button will increase. It seems the _ uses some extra padding. Can I control this somehow?

Update:
[image]

The Margin and Padding is set in App.xaml. E.g. the "Create type hint" button uses this settings properly. The "First" button is clearly bigger than the "Create type hint" button. If I remove the shortcut from the "First" button then its size will be normal.

**Update 2:** Here you can see a WrapPanel and below it the corresponding style in App.xaml. You can see on the second figure that first button is bigger and the only difference is the _. I tried to recreate the problem in an empty project but there the two button had the same size.

```
    <WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="_Decide types"/>
            <Button Content="Decide types"/>               
    </WrapPanel>


    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific about exactly what is wrong, and also please update your question with code that reproduces the issue. Just using the XAML you posted, I don't see any major difference between a button using `_` and one that doesn't.

Comment: I don't see anything either.  You say you set the margin and padding, but your code doesn't show this.  What problem does the button size cause?  Some mis-arrangement in rest of the window?

Comment: If you are talking about first row, it looks like you have some margin on your textbox elements that causes the whole row to stretch. Removing the marging or settings the buttons VerticalAlginment=Center should help.

Comment: @ghord   I already tried VerticalAlginment=Center, please see Update 2

Comment: Use the Live Visual Tree to see if there is something different in how the two buttons are constructed.  Maybe one is built with a `TextBlock` inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there was a style which was active (not in App.xaml), see below. If I delete this style then the size difference disappear between a button with and without shortcut. I have no idea how this is connected to a TextBlock style.

Thank you for the hints.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even using update 2, I don't get the same results as you. Without having access to all of your XAML and styles, it's impossible to tell what might be causing this issue.

[image]

With that said, I recommend that you standardize the height of your buttons so they are all consistent in your app. Since you already have an implicit `Button` style, you might want to add a setter for the `Height` property.

Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/> <-- whatever looks good for your app
</Style>
```